# Rails: Set attribute value to nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a timer function for a task manager that has Play/Pause/Reset/Stop/Complete that effects certain attributes for a Task such as `started_at`, `paused_at`, `resumed_at`, and `done`. I have successfully set the Play/Pause/Reset/Complete appropriately but I want Stop to make the `started_at` value back to nil. This is the part that I cannot get the syntax to function properly.

Here's my buttons for Reset & Complete:

```
<%= link_to raw("<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-refresh\"></i> Reset"), task_path(task, "task[started_at]" => DateTime.now), :method => :put, :confirm => "Sure?", class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" %>
<%= link_to raw("<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok\"></i> Complete"), task_path(task, "task[done]" => true), :method => :put, :confirm => "Sure?", class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" %>
```

Here's my unsuccessful attempt at Stop:

```
<%= link_to raw("<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-refresh\"></i> Reset"), task_path(task, "task[started_at]" => nil), :method => :put, :confirm => "Sure?", class: "btn btn-default btn-sm" %>
```

The reason I want to make the value NIL in the first place is I am using the nil condition as a way to tell whether to pause/resume since that means it has or has not been started previously. All other SO questions/answers I saw were how to resolve nil values in the first place or setting default values at the model level. I appreciate any help!

Edit (07/03/14): Here's my error message -

ActionController::ParameterMissing in TasksController#update
param is missing or the value is empty: task

Extracted source (around line #99):
97
98
99
100
101

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:id, :description, :done, :priority, :started_at, :time_limit, :assignee, :creator, :accepted, :project_id, :paused_at, :resumed_at, :time_spent, :due, :duedate, :duetime, :repeat, :importance)
end
```

end

Comment: if you are not getting nil what value are you getting? It may be that you have to check in the controller whether the value returned is empty. `''` would be considered empty.

Comment: @Stratus3D You hit the nail on the head. I should have added the Error message to my post in the first place. Adding it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you write a new action in your controller to reset the timestamp?

**task_controller.rb**

```
def stop
  @task.started_at = nil
  @task.save!

  # Do something
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :tasks do
  member do
    put :stop
  end
end
```

And then change your view to:

`<%= link_to 'somthing', stop_task_path(task), :method => :put`

**Edit:**

I will try to explay why you get
`ActionController::ParameterMissing in TasksController#update param is missing or the value is empty: task`

When you do:

`<%= link_to "something", task_path(task, "task[started_at]" => nil), method: put`

Setting the value of `task[started_at]` to **nil** will actually be ignored by the url helper.

If you have a close look to the generated link it should be something like `/tasks/xx` and as you see there is no **task** param in this url.

As **@Stratus3D** stated in his comment, you could also try to use `''` instead of **nil**. Thus doing the following would work

`<%= link_to "something", task_path(task, "task[started_at]" => ''), method: put`

The generated url would be `/tasks/x?task%5Bstarted_at%5D=` (where *%5B* and *%5D* are respectively `[` and `]` url encoded).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and I appreciate the feedback. Your solution seems the cleanest since it moves the actions to the controller. Unfortunately, it seems to have introduced a new error: NoMethodError in TasksController#stop | undefined method `started_at=' for nil:NilClass | _@task.started_at = nil_ I have updated my original post with the original error I was getting so that may affect the solution you proposed. Thanks again.

Comment: You need to fetch **@tast** before the method gets called. I guess you have a `before_action :set_task` with a `only: [:something]` in your controller? If so just add `:stop` to the array, otherwise fetch the task into the method (`@task = Task.find(params[:id])`)

Comment: Going from `nil' to just '' seems like the cleanest option for now. Much thanks to @DimitriJorge & Stratus3D !

Answer (score 1):

Looking a little bit further at what you are trying to achieve, you may want to introduce a `status` into your task model and have a method doing the `complete` logic for you:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  def complete
    self.status = 'completed'
    self.started_at = nil
    self
  end
end
```

Note: you may not want to set `started_at` to `nil` anymore in this case.

This way from you controller you could have the following endpoint:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

  def complete
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.complete.save

    respond_with @task
  end

end
```

And the route would look like this:

```
resource :tasks do
  put :complete, on: :member
end
```

Finally if you find yourself doing more complicated things with the *state* of your task, you might want to take a look at [state_machine gem](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine).